# Question: BigQueryIO creates one file per input line, is it correct?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm new on Apache Beam and I'm developing a pipeline to get rows from JDBCIO and send them to BigQueryIO. I'm converting the rows to avro files with `withAvroFormatFunction` but it is creating a new file for each row returned by JDBCIO. The same for `withFormatFunction` with json files.

It is so slow to run locally with DirectRunner because it uploads a lot of files to Google Storage. Is this approach good for scaling on Google Dataflow? Is there a better way to deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you specifying the correct schema when using withAvroFormatFunction?

Comment: @rmesteves I'm using the `.withSchema()` method to specify the schema, I saw the BigQueryIO source code and it converts automatically to an avro schema, right?

Comment: I guess you have to create the schema and pass to the method just like in this doc https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html

Comment: [...]
     .withSchema(new TableSchema().setFields(
         ImmutableList.of(
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("timestamp").setType("TIMESTAMP"),
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("exchange").setType("STRING"),
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("symbol").setType("STRING"),
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("price").setType("FLOAT"))))
     .withFormatFunction(quote -> new TableRow().set(..set the columns..))
     .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));

Comment: I'm doing it. I tried the `withFormatFunction` but the behavior is the same. I'm using the `withAvroFormatFunction` by doc recommendation

BigQueryIO.Write.withAvroFormatFunction(SerializableFunction) (recommended) to write data using avro records.

Comment: can you share more info about what transforms are before your BigQueryIO write? Where are you reading data from? What transform is right before the BQIO?

Comment: Like @Pablo said, can you share a snippet of your pipeline and your functions?

Comment: I realized that it is happening when running with `DirectRunner`. I tested it with `DataflowRunner` and it was so fast. My pipeline reads from JDBC and writes to BigQuery, no transformations except the conversion from `ResultSet` to `TableRow`. Now I'm using `withFormatFunction` because using the Avro format did not work very well with the logical types like date and numeric. I was looking the Apache Beam source code and saw new methods for it for the next release.

Comment: ```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    p.apply("Get last sent id", getLastSent(NestedValueProvider.of(options.getHistoryTable(), new BuildQueryLastSent())))
      .apply("List", list(options.getDriverClass(), options.getConnectionUrl(), options.getUsername(), options.getPassword()))
      .apply("Write", write(options.getOutputTable()));

p.run();
```

Comment: Maybe the conversion from ResultSet to TableRow is the cause of your problem. Did you try not doing it?

Comment: BigQuery needs table rows to process them, result set is the JDBCIO output

Comment: Is the performance problem only on the direct runner? It is known to have very small bundles, and BigQueryIO import jobs are controlled by the size of the bundles.

Comment: Yes the same pipeline takes 3 hours to run on the direct runner and 8 minutes on the Dataflow runner. This topic was created to find a reason to this difference since I can't found the answer in documentation

Comment: If you have a large set of data Dataflow will be much faster than DirectRunner because it uses distributed processing and scale automatically

Answer (score 1):

In BigqueryIO there is an option to specify `withNumFileShards` which controls the number of files that get generated while using Bigquery Load Jobs.

From the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withNumFileShards-int-)

```
Control how many file shards are written when using BigQuery load jobs. Applicable only when also setting withTriggeringFrequency(org.joda.time.Duration).
```

You can set test your process by setting the value to 1 to see if only 1 large file gets created.

Comment: Yes but it is used only for unbounded PCollection, mine is bounded (a JDBC resultset)

Answer (score 1):

BigQueryIO will commit results to BigQuery for each bundle. The DirectRunner is known to be a bit inefficient about bundling. It never combines bundles. So whatever bundling is provided by a source is propagated to the sink. You can try using other runners such as Flink, Spark, or Dataflow. The in-process open source runners are about as easy to use as the direct runner. Just change `--runner=DirectRunner` to `--runner=FlinkRunner` and the default settings will run in local embedded mode.